# Access denied for user 'shopperbeauty_la'@'localhost' after upload L5 to tigrimigri.com

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I developed my application with laravel5.2.I upload it to tigrmagri.com .
when I browse I get this error.

```
PDOException in Connector.php line 55:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'eshopperbeauty_d'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

This is my .env file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:pYTr3QONPElA6XtWYdvWSOwpdw5A+h2uZ/FiiGp+YYU=
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=freehost.tigrimigri.com
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE="eshopperbeauty_db"
DB_USERNAME="eshopperbeauty_db"
DB_PASSWORD="......"


CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=stmp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

I amazed why when I create user like eshopperbeauty_db I get error with eshopperbeauty_d I try many but the same error.

And when I go to

```
http://freehost.tigrimigri.com/phpMyAdmin/
```

to show my user by
`select * from mysql.user`;
I get this error

```
#1142 - SELECT command denied to user 'eshopperbeauty'@'localhost' for table 'user'
```

please any one help me

Answer (score 0):

In mysql,

```
grant all on user.* TO eshopperbeauty@"localhost" identified by "password";
```

You should give the password you are using here

Comment: I try this and get this error    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''@'localhost identified by "password"' at line 1

Comment: I have changed the code. plz try that. And you have to replace "password" with your password.

Comment: @AzharNabil , I have changed the query and just try that.

Comment: The problem was at the host user name database . The host support solve it and it works.